# CSS float prevents expansion of page

Tags: css, css-float

This is a very common scenario, I think.

I'm relatively (no pun intended) new to CSS and am having an issue with float alignment. I have two `div`s, one which will hold main content to be floated `left` and the other for navigation, which should be floated `right`.

Anyway, here is what happens when I *don't* apply any CSS formatting. This is desired behavior; the page will scroll down as expected:
[Desired behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAh4z.png)

Here is what happens when I apply `float: left` or `float: right` to the respective elements:
[Undesired page overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHubN.png)

They both overflow past the page. I want it to stretch the page so that it scrolls down if it doesn't fit on one screen area.

A snippet of my HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content">
    <div id="main">
        <p>Lorem ipsum [...snip...]</p>
    </div>
    <div id="secondary">
        <p>Lorem ipsum [...snip...]</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">&copy;</div>
</div>
</body>
```

And the corresponding CSS:

```
#content {
    padding:10px;
    padding-top: 110px;
    padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}

#main {
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    width:70%;
    text-align:left;
}

#secondary {
    padding: 10px;
    float: right;
    width:20%;
}
```

Why is it doing this, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear the floats and you should be OK.

For example according to your example:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content">
    <div id="main">
        <p>Lorem ipsum [...snip...]</p>
    </div>
    <div id="secondary">
        <p>Lorem ipsum [...snip...]</p>
    </div>

    <!-- clear -->
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">&copy;</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Update: for older IE browsers, the clearing div might need a height defined to give it a "hasLayout" property or else it will ignore this div.
http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

Generally, people make a class definition that has all this info so you only need to type `<div class="clear"></div>`

Here's an example of robust clearing CSS from http://sonspring.com/journal/clearing-floats

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

There are alternative methods to clear floats in the parent div and removing the extra, structural `<div>` tag but I personally don't feel a need to investigate if they are bullet-proof if this solution definitely is.

Comment: Please, please, please, do not use this method! There is no reason to bloat your markup with unnecessary divs.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. To each his own. I don't like overflow:hidden because it can cause problems with relative position, and the :after type fixes need even more confusing markup and browser specific rules.

Comment: I downvoted because I absolutely hate when I see <div style="clear:both;"></div>. It's messy code, and it shouldn't be done, ever. There is always another solution.

Comment: Especially when you are teaching others how to code, separating content from layout is ESSENTIAL. <div style="clear:both;"></div> Violates that separation.

Comment: At least it's simple and reliable. :)

Comment: Then we need a war with the CSS grid people. There are always pros and cons.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do understand your problem with the non structural div. It's just rock solid, easy to understand, widespread, etc. I don't mind it, you do. End of story. We can still be friends. Hopefully.

Answer (score 1):

Any floating element will increase the height of container div, so a floating element may have 1000 lines of code yet height of its parent element will remain zero unless there is an block element after the floating element..

I've modified your code a bit

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper" class="clrfx">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content">
    <div id="main" class="clrfx">
        <p>Lorem ipsum [...snip...]</p>
    </div>
    <div id="secondary" class="clrfx">
        <p>Lorem ipsum [...snip...]</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">&copy;</div>
</div>
</body>
```

css:

```
.clrfx:after {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    content: "";
}
```

Rule of thumb is, assign class="clrfx" to any Div which has atleast one child element which is floating. Some people use `<div class="clear"></div>` but this SHOULD NOT be used as clearing is a part of styling and not of markup.

In worst case if you have to use this then I would advise use

```
<br class="clear" />
```

because breaking line is close to clearing

Answer (score 0):

As you said that you were new to CSS: Floated elements have no height. Therefore `#content` is defaulting to minimum height, which is the combined height of the paddings.

Adding `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` after `div#secondary` will force it to below the floated elements. As this div *does* have a height, it causes `#main` to behave as expected. See [Yuji's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663279/css-float-prevents-expansion-of-page/4663337#4663337) for sample code.

Comment: That's incorrect.  Floated elements have height.  The relevant factor is that they are not part of the flow.

Answer (score 0):

Floating elements are removed from the flow, so they are not taken into consideration when their parent element's height is being calculated and their parent element is set to `overflow: visible`.

You can either place a dummy element beneath the floated elements (forcing the dummy element to the correct place with the `clear` property), or you can set the parent element to something other than `overflow: visible`.

Answer (score 0):

To make your wrapper contain all floated elements, simply set;

```
#wrapper {overflow: hidden;}
```

Simple, and you're done. No extra markup.